# Integrate google assistant with external chat bot data source instead of sing dialog flow or actions on google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We are trying to develop an application with Google Assistant. We already have a chat bot data source. Is it possible to connect Google Assistant to a third party data source instead of using Dialogflow. So in the final solution the Google Assistant will act as speech to text and text to speech medium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can take a look at the [Action SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/), which will POST to your webhook containing a JSON payload that includes the speech-to-text, and receive a response from you a JSON payload consisting of your reply.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Now I got an idea how to use it. Can you also suggest how can I deploy a sample action sdk node.js project into aws lambda? all the google samples are based on firebase cloud functions.

Comment: I have found something here. https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/. But don't know how to use it.

Comment: That sounds like a different question. I suggest you post it as a new SO question with some more details about what you've tried and what, exactly, is confusing you.